# Disabling the EF Object graph for a query

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-4.1, dbcontext, object-graph

Im doing caching in an application, on app start I pre-fetch a few million rows of data from a database and jam it into a local cache.

My problem is that during the fetch operation when I am loading all of that data via EF the object graph gets enormous (around 4GB, which disappears as soon as I dispose the context). I would like to be able to tell EF not to track any objects inside the scope of this query (or lifetime of the context) so that my application doesn't run out of memory.

Is there a good way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [AsNoTracking](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg679169%28v=vs.103%29.aspx) method

```
var entities = dbContext.MyEntities.Where(/**/).AsNoTracking();
```

Comment: Awesome, works perfectly and also drops the query time as well :)

Comment: @LukeMcGregor Yes taking a snapshot takes considerable time. This avoids it.